# Make a Barplot from the means of two variables in R

Tags: r, aggregate, bar-chart

I'm having real trouble creating a simple bar plot. I am looking at the parasite load in mackerel, and want to create a bar plot that shows the difference in mean parasite load in male and female fish (with error bars).
At the moment, my data includes a column titled as SEX, under which fish are classed as M or F. Another column shows the number of parasites in each individual.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide any data so we cannot respond precisely, but I will illustrate with other data and then say what I think you need. Using the built-in iris data:

```
Tab = aggregate(iris$Sepal.Length, list(iris$Species), mean)
barplot(Tab$x, names.arg=Tab$Group.1)
```

[image: Barplot]

So you probably need something like:

```
Tab = aggregate(DAT$parasites, list(DAT$SEX), mean)
barplot(Tab$x, names.arg=Tab$Group.1)
```